# I am making a trivia game. every answer brings up the correct page. how do i fix this?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
        button1();
    }
    if(array_key_exists('button2', $_POST)) {
        button2();
    }
    if(array_key_exists('button3', $_POST)) {
        button3();
    }
    if(array_key_exists('button4', $_POST)) {
        button4();
    }
    function button1() {
        if ($correct == $answer1){
            header("Location: correct.php"); 
        }
        else 
            {header("Location: wrong.php");
            
        }
    }
    function button2() {
        if ($correct == $answer2){
            header("Location: correct.php"); 
        }
        else {
            header("Location: wrong.php");
            
        }
    }
    function button3() {
        if ($correct == $answer3){
            header("Location: correct.php"); 
        }
        else {
            header("Location: wrong.php");
            
        }
    }
    function button4() {
        if ($correct == $answer4){
            header("Location: correct.php"); 
        }
        else {
            header("Location: wrong.php");
            
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1"
            class="button" value="<?php echo $answer1?>" />
      
    <input type="submit" name="button2"
            class="button" value="<?php echo $answer2?>" />
            
    <input type="submit" name="button3"
            class="button" value="<?php echo $answer3?>" />
            
    <input type="submit" name="button4"
            class="button" value="<?php echo $answer4?>" />
</form>
```

this should compare the correct answer with whatever they clicked but for some reason just always says its correct. All variables are defined earlier in the code and are sourced from a database. I tried using javascript for tis however all my variables are in php so I was unable to compare answers.

Comment: can you `var_dump` `$_POST` and all other variables, and put the result here

Comment: No explanation of where $correct or $answer* comes from. Where did they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initialising variables that are out of scope when you're testing the answers.

You have some code that amounts to this:

```
    $answer1 = 1;
    $correct = 2;
    button1();

    function button1() {
        if ($correct == $answer1){
            header("Location: correct.php"); 
        }
        else 
            {header("Location: wrong.php");
            
        }
    }
```

The variables initialised at the top are out of scope inside the function . PHP treats the variables inside the function as undefined (since they're not initialiased) and assigns them both the value `null`. Hence the test is passed, and the `correct.php` page is loaded.

You don't need the function calls here at all. You could just do this

```
    if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
        if ($correct == $answer1){
            header("Location: correct.php");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: wrong.php");
        }
    }
```

I suspect, though, that the real solution here involves a different approach from the start.

Take a look at the PHP page on [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)